# Maximum checked-in files in Perforce

Tags: perforce, checkin

We use perforce. In the repository, how can I find which files are checked-in maximum number of times?

I know via P4win, one  can manually go to each folder and file and then see the number with file. I have really big repository and many folders & files. So, but I am looking an more automated way or better suggestion so that I can avoid manual work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

'p4 files' will print the list of all the files in the repository, and for each file it will tell you the revision number. Then a little bit of 'awk' and 'sort' will find the files with the highest revision numbers.